# Statistics in multi-tenancy mode on CEF Context Broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I would like to know if there is a way to extract the statistics for each client, when Orion is running in multi-tenancy mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [metrics API documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/metrics_api/index.html),  metrics are provided per service and service path:

```
{
  "services": {
    "service1": <service 1 info>,
    "service2": <service 2 info>,
    ...
    "serviceN": <service N info>
  }
  "sum": <aggregated info for all services>
}
```

and per each service info object:

```
{
  "subservs": {
    "subservice1": <subservice 1 info>,
    "subservice2": <subservice 2 info>,
    ...
    "subserviceN": <subservice N info>
  }
  "sum": <aggregated info for all subservice in the given service>
}
```